# Setting variable to last arg from command line parameters

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I'm trying to write a script in a way that makes it simple to add future command line args.  I'm using getopts and that works well.  However, I'm running into issues with the case statement.

```
args=`getopt lLo:t: $*`
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
   echo "Usage: Default error message"
fi

while [ "$#" -eq 3 ] || [ "$#" -eq 5 ]
do 
   if [ "$1" != "-o" ] && [ "$1" != "-t" ]
   then
      echo "\nInvalid argument sequence."
      exit 1
   fi

   case "$1" in
   (-o)
      shift
      VAR1="$1"
      shift
      ;;
   (-t)
      shift
      VAR2="$1"
      shift
      ;;
   (*)
      LAST_VAR="$1"
      ;;
   (--) shift; break;;
 esac
done
```

If I then echo $LAST_VAR it is null.  Any ideas?  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @l0b0 Thanks!  My actual code has the spaces there, and I didn't know I could exclude the ( in case matching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some findings:

- You need spaces around each `[` and `]` (line 2). See `help [`.
- You don't need `(` in case matchings. See `help case`.
- You can use `VAR1="$2"` and `shift 2` instead of two separate shifts. See `help shift`.
- You want to put the `--` case before `*`, and move the `break` to the `*` case.
- Follow the logic backwards: `LAST_VAR` will be set if `$1` is neither `-o` nor `-t`. Before that you `exit` if `$1` is neither `-o` nor `-t`. So `LAST_VAR` can never be set.

I would suggest looking at some `getopt` examples for some ideas. Shameless plug for some [tested code](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/master/scripts/make-links.sh):

```
# Process parameters
params="$(getopt -o d:e:fshv \
    -l diff:,exclude:,force,skip-existing,help,verbose \
    --name "$cmdname" -- "$@")"

if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
    usage
fi

eval set -- "$params"
unset params

while true
do
    case $1 in
        -d|--diff)
            diff_exec=(${2-})
            shift 2
            ;;
        -e|--exclude)
            # Will override $default_excludes
            excludes+=("${2-}")
            shift 2
            ;;
        -f|--force)
            action='R'
            shift
            ;;
        -s|--skip-existing)
            action='S'
            shift
            ;;
        -h|--help)
            usage
            exit
            ;;
        -v|--verbose)
            verbose='--verbose'
            shift
            ;;
        --)
            shift
            if [ -z "${1:-}" ]
            then
                error "Missing targets." "$help_info" $EX_USAGE
            fi
            if [ -z "${2:-}" ]
            then
                error "Missing directory." "$help_info" $EX_USAGE
            fi
            targets=(${@:1:$(($#-1))})
            source_dir="${@:$#}"
            break
            ;;
        *)
            usage
            ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: on the line where I have the if statement, am I managing the sequence of the args properly?  I feel like it could become a long if statement if there are like 5 args...

Comment: @nkon You don't need that `if` statement. It's a lot simpler if you simply loop through all the arguments and trust `getopt` to check if there are values where there should be.

Comment: What is the -o on the first line with the getopt param list?

Comment: @nkon Please at least check the `man` page before asking - It's the option for specifying command options.

Comment: @nkon Sorry, then you're probably using a different version. As in your original code, it should probably work without `-o`.